# Why am I suddenly not able to connect to my PC with VNC any more (no connection or grey display)?

Tags: vnc

I am running a mini PC and suddenly was not able to connect to the PC any more with VNC. The PC has no monitor attached (but a fake HDMI dongle).

I was able to start `vnc-manager` via `ssh` and then connected successfully to my `IP:port+displaynumber` as I was told from the response of the command. But the VNC client just showed a grey display.

I suspected a faulty login to the desktop session. Last time I had a similar problem there was a rights issue with the `.Xauthority` file.

But this was not the case this time.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Is this a standard comment? I will not change because I like the clean desktop environment and the PC is just running as a minor server internally.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by standard comment.  Site rules say only supported releases (not development, EOL/ESM etc), and Ubuntu doesn't want to encourage people using unsupported or past-EOL software, thus you'll not get much support from people associated with Ubuntu projects, flavors, members etc. We of course are happy for people to continue using our software past its supported life, but you're on your own, and cannot any longer use Canonical/Ubuntu infrastructure (*this is an official Ubuntu site*).

Comment: FYI:   I include the FYI as informational notice only, personally I don't vote to close a partially supported release, however I also skip the question & leave the FYI you're EOL notice (some users aren't aware they're using unsupported software, assuming *flavors* have the same 5 years as main Ubuntu does).  Were your release fully unsupported there would have been no "FYI:" and I would have close-voted.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My question is not so much about Ubuntu or the specific release. It is about the deskopt environment not starting up due to a full disk. And therefore a faulty connection via VNC. Maybe i was unclear in stating the question.

Comment: So you mean the problem I stated can not occur any more in supported versions? A full disk can not prevent the startup of the desktop environment (or how you call it in later versions)?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a **full disk** which prevented the `openbox-session` from running.

First I tried to run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` to check if another one of the sessions might open up and I was confused because the `*` pointed to `gnome` while I was running `openbox` normally.

When I tried to start `/usr/bin/startlxde` manually from command line the return indicated that my disk is full:

```
mkdtemp: private socket dir: No space left on device
```

A faulty mount was the reason.

I also explained this in a thread and will link it here because it is very relevant but there is not much on google (the forum is for RaspberryPi but this happened on an Ubuntu OS to me): https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=194764&p=1755103#p1755103